# Перенести товары с сайта на другой сайт

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, миграция

Как можно оперативно перенести товары с одного сайта на другой? Какой инструмент использовать, может, есть видео подробное?

Вот сайт донор: vk.cc/330NKE
Перенести сюда: vk.cc/34g0Md

Переносить нужно со всеми изображениями, аттрибутами, описанием.
Некоторые позиции на сайте донноре повторяются, их переносить не нужно.

Например: joxi.ru/752a8WgnFnGVm0

Comment: @goldway, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: @goldway, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Прочитайте про `API` ну и копайте в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Движок ваших сайтов определяется как CMS OpenCart. Соответственно, Вам необходимо найти расширение OpenCart для экспорт\импорта товаров, либо перенести вручную необходимые данные с помощью любого менеджера баз данных MySQL (phpMyAdmin, например).

**Обновление**

Без доступа к админке сайта - НЕТ. Как первого, так и второго сайта. :) Ну и, скорей всего, потребуется доступ к каталогам сайтов на серверах хостинга - думаю, что фотки придется вручную заливать. Ну, а с чем лучше работать, то протестируйте модуль - если переносит, то зачемaa лезть к базе вручную. (Большего не подскажу, я в основном работаю с CMS Joomla.)

Comment: Скажите, с чем бы вы посоветовали лучше сработать? Для этого подойдет Модуль Экспорт / Импорт для OpenCart 1.5.1 - 1.5.1.3? И можно ли это сделать без админ пароля от сайта?

Comment: Обновил ответ